# How can i get results out from firestore query

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

```
componentDidMount(){
    let select=[];
    let result=[];
    let tagsSelected=this.state.tagsSelected
    tagsSelected.forEach(element => {
      select.push(element.name)
    });
    symptomsRef.where("Symptom", "array-contains-any", select).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => (doc.id));
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

I would like help with how can i get the array in const data to copy to result array. i mean i want to take it out of query,

Comment: In your example code, what is the result of data when you run it?

Comment: Are you  getting any errors? Or as asked by @Brettski, what does data prints to the console?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Firebase Firestore Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains-any), in your scenario, the query with **array-contains-any** returns every Symptom document where the Symptom field is an array that contains any of the ***elements you have in the select array.***

So it will return you all the documents where the field **Symtom** has one of the elements defined in **Select** array.

You can use **await** to get all the documents however **.then(querySnapShot)** also works:

```
const documents = await symptomsRef.where("Symptom", "array-contains-any", select).get()
```

Then you can iterate over the documents to get [the document data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query) as following:

```
if (documents.empty) {
  console.log('No matching documents.');
  return;
}  

documents.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
});
```

You can save the document data or any of the document field you want in a list or in a const in order to perform the tasks you want as following:

```
let ids=[];
documents.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  ids.push(doc.id);

  //OR

  const id = doc.id;

});
```